# MLE for bivariate Normal distribution and Fisher Information

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, marginal-distribution, fisher-information

I got very confused trying to understand the meaning of Fisher information, and link it with the information for parameters contained in samples.

Suppose $(X_1,X_2) \sim \mathcal{N}(\begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \\ \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2 \end{bmatrix})$, let $x^1=(x^1_1,x^1_2)^T,\;\ldots,\;x^n=(x^n_1,x^n_2)^T$ be $n$ samples from this bivariate normal distribution. Then the MLE for $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are clearly
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x^i \qquad
\hat{\Sigma} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x^i-\hat{\mu})(x^i-\hat{\mu})^T.
\end{equation}
If we only care about the marginal distribution for $X_1$, then
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mu}_1 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x^i_1 \qquad
\hat{\sigma}_1^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x^i_1-\hat{\mu}_1)(x^i_1-\hat{\mu}_1)^T.
\end{equation}
This means when trying to get the MLE only for $X_1$, we only need to look at $x_1^i$, and completely ignore $x_2^i$. However, when looking at the Fisher information for $\sigma_1$, something opposite happens.
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}_{\sigma_1\sigma_1}(X_1,X_2) = \frac{2}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{\rho^2}{1-\rho^2} \frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}.
\end{equation}
And by chain rule $\mathcal{I}_{\sigma_1\sigma_1}(X_1,X_2) = \mathcal{I}_{\sigma_1\sigma_1}(X_1) + \mathcal{I}_{\sigma_1\sigma_1}(X_2|X_1)$, and $\mathcal{I}_{\sigma_1\sigma_1}(X_1) = \frac{2}{\sigma_1^2}$, $\mathcal{I}_{\sigma_1\sigma_1}(X_2|X_1) = \frac{\rho^2}{1-\rho^2} \frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}$.

My interpretation of Fisher information is it represents the amount of information of the parameter contained in the samples. However, from the above calculation, it seems there is some information of $\sigma_1$ contained in $X_2$; whereas from the MLE, it seems $\sigma_1$ can be estimated by completely ignoring $X_2$. These observations are contradictory, so is there anything wrong in my interpretations? Thanks in advance!